Local table of content heading too large with etoc
I am using the scrbook document class. At the top of my file, I have a table of contents which contains only parts, chapters and sections, constructed with \tableofcontents. Then, I later use \localtableofcontents from the etoc package to construct a table of contents with subsections and subsubections. However, each time I call \localtableofcontents, it starts a new page, has the large "Contents" heading, and has lots of whitespace. This is not the behavior I am used to in article, and so want \localtableofcontents to

Not create a new page
Have section* formatting (white space, font size, etc.)

and did not know how to go about doing this. Any help appreciated, I am completely new to scrbook and KOMA-Script.
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    oneside,
    openright,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    titlepage=false,
    paper=letter,
]{scrbook}

% Standard
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
% Local table of contents
\usepackage{etoc}

% Title page
\title{Example}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Only include part, chapter, section in main TOC
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Local TOC now contain subsection and subsubsection

\mainmatter
\chapter{Fall 2024}

\section{Example section}

\section{Example other section}

\localtableofcontents

\subsection{Example subsection}

\subsection{Example other subsection}

\subsubsection{Example subsubsection}

\end{document}



If you add to the documentclass options: "headings=small" -- does the result meet your expectations?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

@KeksDose thank you for the suggestion. That option achieves 2. for me, however the local table of contents still instantiates a \newpage, meaning the section header that the local toc belongs to is on an empty page. Is this because the toc header is inheriting something from part or chapter, meaning it creates a \newpage?

Is your LaTeX installation up-to-date? With an up-to-date KOMA-Script and etoc I get: https://i.imgur.com/EumOPUe.png and therefore cannot reproduce your output. The local ToC is already on subsection level and does not start a new page. Same with older KOMA-Script and etoc of TeX Live 2023 and 2022. I can reproduce the problem only with TeX Live 2021 and older. So IMHO you should update your TeX distribution.

BTW: With outdated version of etoc, e.g., v1.09e 2021/09/23, this also happens with book. So the problem is not really KOMA-Script related.  With etoc v1.2 2023/03/01 and newer it does not happen. See the end of section 1 of the etoc documentation for the relevant change in version 1.2. So the problem is mainly because of using an old etoc and an update would solve it.

Thank you, I have since updated my environment, which fixed the issue without the introduction of additional macros. I will leave my answer as is, as it further decreases whitespace compared to simply using the stock \localtableofcontents, which I prefer in my context in case it is of use to future readers. I will add an edit showing the stock and custom options when I get the chance.

I was able to prevent the page break using etoc after following part of this answer
\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand{\sectiontoc}{%
    \begingroup
    \parbox[b]{0.96\textwidth}{
        \vspace{-1em}
        \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Entry contents}}{}
        \localtableofcontents
    }
    \endgroup
}


There's no need of \parbox: just \etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Entry contents}{} suffices.

@egreg removing the \parbox leads to the \localtableofcontents having drastically different spacing, at least in my (now updated) environment. It could be a result of having changed other properties, but removing the \parbox results in a different behavior which I do not prefer

Of course the parskip option enters the scene… If you want bad typesetting, continue to use it.

I am sorry that I am a beginner and not familiar with what is and isn't best practices, but using that tone cannot be the best way for you to inform new people what to use and what not to use. Including links to information on good typesetting would be far more useful to me then being snide.

You want to neutralize the nonzero parskip in the local table of contents.
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    oneside,
    openright,
    numbers=noenddot,
    parskip=half,
    titlepage=false,
    paper=letter,
]{scrbook}

% Standard
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
% Local table of contents
\usepackage{etoc}

% Title page
\title{Example}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1} % Only include part, chapter, section in main TOC
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % Local TOC now contain subsection and subsubsection

\mainmatter
\chapter{Fall 2024}

\section{Example section}

\section{Example other section}

\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Entry contents}\setlength\parskip{0pt}}{}
\localtableofcontents

\subsection{Example subsection}

text

text

\subsection{Example other subsection}

\subsubsection{Example subsubsection}

\end{document}


